# How to remove duplicate links in text file?

Tags: python, parsing, hyperlink, duplicates, text-parsing

So I have a text file that inside looks like this:

```
http://example.pl/folder/this_same1.avi
http://example.pl/folder/this_same1.avi
http://example.pl/folder/this_same2.avi
http://example.pl/folder/this_same2.avi
http://example.pl/folder/this_same3.avi
http://example.pl/folder/this_same3.avi
```

And I want to delete all the duplicate links. 
To the output file looks like this:

```
http://example.pl/folder/this_same1.avi
http://example.pl/folder/this_same2.avi
http://example.pl/folder/this_same3.avi
```

Comment: `cat /path/to/file | sort -u`

Comment: @NehalJWani Assuming OP is using Linux...

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that structure is consistent and order is important:

```
links = fp.readlines()[::2]
```

If structure is not consistent, and order is important:

```
links = []
for line in fp.readlines():
    if line not in links:
        links.append(line)
```

Then write to file.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I've improved my answer:

```
links = set()
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        links.add(line)
```

Then you can write back to the file:

```
with open('file.txt', 'wb') as fp:
    for line in links:
        fp.write(line)
```

Test it yourself..

Comment: The explicit `for` loop is unnecessary: `set(fp.readlines())` will do. Also note that this may (and probably will) modify the order of the lines. OP may or may not be ok with it.